# Moodle "error/forcepasswordchangenotice" on user create

Tags: web-services, moodle, moodle-api

I am creating a new User via Webservice. 
My new user has following attributes -

```
 {
        "username":"newuser1",
        "password":"Neel@123",
        "firstname":"Neel",
        "lastname":"Bhave",
        "email":"b@c.com"
    }
```

However, when I submit it through GET request, I get the following response -

```
{
    "exception": "moodle_exception",
    "errorcode": "forcepasswordchangenotice",
    "message": "error/forcepasswordchangenotice"
}
```

How do I solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue. 
The issue was that the user that I was using for the web services had **force password reset checked** while creation. I had not logged in once the user was created and was only using it for the Webservice. Hence I was this error was showing up. I **unchecked force password reset** from my admin account and it was solved.